# Auto.arima modeled on multiple data points

Tags: r, arima, forecast

I am trying to run auto.arima on a dataset containing thousands of rows. In the dataset there are hundreds of unique domains, i'd like auto.arima to run on each domain individually and return the forecast results in a data.frame.

Here's an example of the dataset:

```
| Date     |   Domain       | Impressions |
| -------- | -------------- | ---------   |
| 1/13/2023| red.com        | 957         |
| 1/14/2023| red.com        | 1015        |
| 1/13/2023| blue.com       | 800         |
| 1/14/2023| blue.com       | 936         |
| 1/13/2023| pink.com       | 970         |
| 1/14/2023| pink.com       | 712         |

these_domains <- test$domain %>% unique()
yup_rate_delivery <- these_domains %>% 
  map(function(this_domain){
    test <- test %>% filter(domain == this_domain)
    {rate <- ts(test[,'net_cpm'],start =c(2021,11), frequency = 12)
      autoplot(rate) +ggtitle("net_cpm_rate") + ylab("rate")
      fit_ARIMA <- auto.arima(net_cpm, seasonal = TRUE)}
  }) %>% set_names(these_domains)
```

I have tried auto.arima as part of a map function but it just returns the results in a list that can't be converted into a data frame. I also don't think it ran correctly as i can't seem to see the forecast when i view the list.

Comment: This looks like a good use case for [tidyverts](https://tidyverts.org/), the successor to `forecast`, with Date as the index and Domain as the key.

Comment: A great way to include a dataset is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Comment: You can also add your output list using dput. It's usually much better to update the question than to add comments.